# SUMIFS ARRAYFORMULA returns blank cell if the value is 0, how do I force it to show 0

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, countif, sumifs

Here's my formula for the cell `K37`:

`=IFERROR(1/(1/ArrayFormula(sumifs($H37:$H,$E37:$E,"ABC",MONTH($G37:$G),1))))`

the cell `K37` returns nothing (it's blank) when there's no cells in `$E37:$E` range with the `"ABC"` criteria and some value in corresponding `$H37:$H` range's cell. And it's fine!

But how do I force the formula to return `0` instead of just a blank cell if there's at least one cell in `$E37:$E` range, satisfying the `"ABC"` criteria with the actual `$0.00` value in corresponding `$H37:$H` range's cell?

                 `E`           `G`            `H`           `K` 

`37`          ABC       Jan-1     $0.00      blank (but I want it to be 0)

`38`

`39`

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Added some visuals.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way:

***K37***

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIFS($E37:$E,"ABC",MONTH($G37:$G),1),IFERROR(1/(1/SUMIFS($H37:$H,$E37:$E,"ABC",MONTH($G37:$G),1)),0),""))
```

Check if value exists, if #DIV/0! return 0, otherwise return blank.

Comment: @tryingout I think you must count the occurrence of your criteria (ABC) to check if have value to sum. In this case, you can divide 1 for 1/sum, only if is error mean you have a 0 as sum and display 0. If you don't have record with ABC the formula must show blank. But if you are satisfied by correction I'm glade for you

Comment: You're right. Your formula does the trick as it is! Thanks!